# Graceful shutdown with option to save files or cancel

Tags: desktop-environment, shutdown

How do I shutdown a desktop session gracefully from the command line without root, giving programs the option to ask the user to save files or cancel the shutdown? I know `shutdown`, `halt`, and other similar methods aren't viable, since they will just ask every process to end and forcibly kill it a few seconds later. They also require root, which I want to avoid. When shutting down, a program with unsaved files should be able to block the shutdown process or cancel it, if the user chooses to do so. I believe the answer has something to do with DBus, but from what I understand every desktop session has a different dbus interface to use. Most results in online searches either point to `shutdown`/`halt` or to a Gnome or KDE-specific solution. Is there a method that works for all desktop environments, or will I always need a list of dbus commands to try and cover every desktop?

Comment: Try `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-session-quit --logout`